# Laptop starts up, runs perfectly normally for a few minutes, fan starts spinning very fasts, then shuts down

Tags: laptop, shutdown, fan

I left my Metabox p150 laptop underneath my bed for about a month, and now I have a problem where I can start up my computer, login and do anything normally for a few minutes, until the fan starts running extremely fast for a little while (under a minute) and the computer shuts down suddenly. When the fan is running fast, is accompanied by a very loud continuous beeping noise, even though my volume is on zero. I have already cleaned the fan and the vents so that it is no longer dusty at all, however the problem persists. This also happens on safe mode, and can happen even when I'm just on the bios setup menu. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: It really sounds like an overheating problem (not unusual in laptops). Have you opened up the laptop & made certain there is no blockage in the cooling system?

Answer (score 0):

The loud beep you hear is coming from the on-board piezo speaker, rather than your normal audio speakers. Many laptops (and PCs) - when you turn them on - emit one or more beeps to signify POST success or failure. One short beep is mostly a successful POST, multiple beeps often signifies problems during POST and is often a hardware problem relating to CPU, RAM or other vital hardware.

The fact your laptop has been under your bed for a while tells me it's gathered dust (or even an insect or two!) around the CPU, heatsink or fan/fan exhaust and the processor is unable to cool correctly so it turns itself off to prevent thermal damage that could completely destroy your processor.

To fix it: You could try buying a small can of compressed air to blow any dust away from core components (through the fan exhaust port and other cooling vents), take it apart to inspect/clean or take it to a specialist who can disassemble your device and professionally repair it....